# Which is more Idiomatic scheme?

Tags: scheme

I'm going through SICP, and for the symbolic differentiator I have come up with two approaches to taking sums of arbitrary numbers of arguments.

One returns sums of many arguments as:

`(make-sum 1 'x 4) -> (+ 4 'x)`

`(make-sum '(+ 3 x) (** x 2) 5) -> (+ 8 x (** x 2))`

and the other does:

`(make-sum 1 'x 4) ->(+ 1 (+ 'x 4))`

`(make-sum '(+ 3 x) (** x 2) 5) -> (+ (+3 x) (+ (** x 2) 5))`

Note that both `make-sum` are not fully functional. My question is not about figuring out how to fix those issues.

First `make-sum`

```
(define (make-sum . ad)
  #|goes through the list ad
  and adds up the numbers, while
  putting non-numeric terms into 
  a separate list, returning a new 
  list with the sum and non-numeric
  term list|#
  (define (accumulate-terms lst)
    (define (accumulate-terms-help lst num-sum other-terms)
      (cond ((null? lst) `(,@other-terms ,num-sum))
            ((number? (car lst)) 
             (accumulate-terms-help (cdr lst)
                                (+ num-sum (car lst))
                                other-terms))
            (else (accumulate-terms-help (cdr lst)
                                     num-sum
                         (cons (car lst) other-terms)))))
    (accumulate-terms-help lst 0 '()))

  #|modified flatten that only flattens
  sub-lists that have sym as their first element|#
  (define (flatten lst sym)
    (cond ((eq? lst '()) '())
          ((list? (car lst))
          (cond ((eq? (caar lst) sym)
             (append (flatten (car lst) sym) (flatten (cdr lst) sym)))
            (else (cons (car lst) (flatten (cdr lst) sym)))))     
          (else
           (cons (car lst) (flatten (cdr lst) sym)))))

  #|flattens out all addition sub terms
  accumulates what is left and then filters
  any zeroes|#
  (let* ()
    (define ret
      (filter (lambda (p)
            (not (eq? p 0)))
              (cond ((> (length ad) 1)
                 `(+ ,@(accumulate-terms
                     (filter (lambda (q)
                           (not (eq? q '+)))
                         (flatten ad '+)))))
                    (else ad))))

    (cond ((> (length ret) 2)
           ret)
          (else (cadr ret)))))
```

Second make-sum

```
(define (make-sum . an)
  (cond
    ((equal? (length an) 1)
      (let ((it (car an)))
        (cond
          ((number? it) it)
          ((variable? it) `',it)
          ((sum? it) (eval `(make-sum ,@it)))
          (else it))))
    (else
      (let ((cur (car an))
           (rest (cdr an)))
        (cond
          ((number? cur)
             `(+ ,cur ,(eval `(make-sum ,@rest))))
          ((variable? cur)
             `(+ ',cur ,(eval `(make-sum ,@rest))))     
          ((sum? cur)
             (let ((ad (addend cur))
                   (ag (augend cur)))
               (cond
               #|if both the addend and augend of cur
               are numbers, returns the sum|#
                 ((and (number? ad)
                   (number? ag))
                   `(+ ,(+ ad ag)
                   ,(eval `(make-sum ,@rest))))

               #|if the addend of cur is a number
               and the augend of cur is a sum|#
                 ((and (number? ad)
                   (sum? ag))
                   (let ((adg (addend ag))
                         (agg (augend ag)))
                     (cond
                       ((number? adg)
                    `(+ ,(+ ad adg)
                        ,(eval `(make-sum agg ,@rest))))

                       ((number? agg)
                    `(+ ,(+ ad agg)
                        ,(eval `(make-sum adg ,@rest))))

                       (else `(+ ,ad
                         ,(eval `(make-sum ,ag
                                   ,@rest)))))))

                 (else `(+ ,cur (eval `(make-sum ,@rest))))))))))))
```

So my question is, which approach is the "schemier" way of doing things,
flattening and filtering a list to transform it into the correct list,
or manually recursing through one with rules for each level of the recursion?
The first example's strength is that its output is more readable `(make-sum 'a 'b 'c) -> (+ a b c)`than the second `(make-sum 'a 'b 'c) -> (+ a (+ b c))`. The second ones strength is that you can take derivatives far more easily, Using only two functions, `addend` and `augend` to select the operators, the derivative is expressed naturally in the way you would deal with them in a calculus class. The first example is much harder to take derivatives with, requiring a mapping of `deriv` to each of the terms and a few filters to ensure correct output.

**EDIT**
Also, I don't like that ive had to use eval so much, but it was the only way I could think of going about inputting an unpacked list to a function like

```
(eval `(foo ,@lst)) ;foo takes any number of arguments
```

Additionally:

```
`',var ; for quoting the result from var
       ; when this term is inside of a qq
```

Seems like something that there is a better way to go about

Comment: I would say that idiomatic Scheme (and idiomatic functional programming in general) is to prefer higher-order functions over explicit recursion wherever possible, provided that they improve readability (and they usually do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scheme, the idiomatic way is to use higher-order functions - compose your solution in terms of `map`, `filter`, `foldl`, `foldr`, `flatten`, etc. (there are many more!) This will lead to shorter solutions, instead of having to explicitly loop over each list.

Also, avoid abusing quasi-quoting, splicing and `eval` :-). All of your code can be rewritten without using them, at this point in the book the authors have not covered them. For instance, this:

```
(eval `(foo ,@lst))
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
(apply foo lst)
```

The above is the preferred way. Similarly, this doesn't make much sense:

```
`',var
```

If `var` is already a symbol, then leave it be, you don't have to quote it again. Bottom line: keep things simple, your code is overly complicated for no reason.

Comment: I want to make the value of var into a symbol, so if (define var  'x)  or (define var (** x 2)) is passed to a function, and gets unquoted `',var will return x or (** x 2) instead of 'var

Comment: But as I stated above, you shouldn't be using `unquote` in the first place... it's not needed for this problem, there are simpler ways to accomplish what's needed for this exercise.